# Move tilde (~) on macbook to the § (±) key for Brazilian Portuguese. How do I adjust the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

Just bought a macbook pro in Dubai with this keyboard layout:

[image]

I'm trying to move the tilde symbol to the § key, but I'm not succeeding. Anyone can help?

best,

D

Comment: As far as I know you can't move individual keys, except for the modifier keys. However you can change your keyboard layout [system prefs > keyboard > input sources] to your natural language and use muscle memory [or keyboard viewer] to know where the keys are. I have a Japanese MacBook that displays another character for the tilde key. Changing my input source to US/ABC gives me back the tilde in the right spot.

Comment: The standard way to remap keys is to use the app Karabiner or make a custom layout using the app Ukelele.  This has been covered many times in this forum if you search.